# Powershell : obtain and install windows updates only until a specific date

Tags: powershell

There are some situations where we need a build which is 100% reproducible (eg development of medical device software).  Is there a way to use powershell to download and install updated UNTIL  a specific date, but without more recent updates?

Alternatively is it possible to obtain the updates, store them offline and then use powershell to reproduce the build with the offline updates.  This would allow us to make a 100% reproducible build without internet access.

Currently we use Windows updates in virtual machine and then store the state of the VM in a .gho file using symantec Ghost suite and we store as well the virtual disk  .vhdx.

Comment: How about WSUS? Set up your own managed update point and config the system so that it will install only updates you have cherry-picked and approved.

Comment: I just checked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/get-started/windows-server-update-services-wsus  WSUS would definitely solve the problem, the issue for us (a small company) is that it requires setting up a windows server and update system.  currently prod computers are deployed without interacting with a windows server (just using scripting).